# Horizontal rule keeps moving position randomly

Tags: html

I have two horizontal rules and some text. One line on top of some text, and the other under the text.

The one that is under keeps moving and I have no idea why. Sometimes, when I refresh the page it's in the right place, sometimes it's not. I tried browsing on a phone as well, same problem.

I just want both lines to be symmetrical with the text in the middle, that's all.

Here is my  code:

```
 <div class="blogpost3">
        <p class="posttitle"><span class="c1">NEW MUSIC VIDEO:<br />
        "IT'S SIMPLE"</span></p>

        <p class="postheader"><span class="c1">Release Date:</span> 1 September
        2013</p>

        <p class="postpicture"><img alt="" src=
        "images/itssimple.jpg" /></p><br />


        <hr id="hr3" />

        <p class="posttext2"><em>&nbsp;Suit and tie. Gin and tonic. Richi
        Rich.</em><br />
        <br />
        &nbsp;It's Simple.<br />
        <br />
        <a class="roll" href="music.html"><span data-title=
        "Watch the video here"><strong>Watch the video
        here.</strong></span></a></p>

        <hr id="hr3" />
    </div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/richirich/A5F8Y/2/

Thanks!